How to add new gpg keys to apt without root
I am installing CuDNN without root. The installation requires adding keys
sudo cp /var/cudnn-local-*/cudnn-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/ and then apt-get update.
I used a custom apt.conf as this link said to run apt without root (use apt source to install the package in a custom location), but I failed to add the corresponding repo of CuDNN.
What I have tried:

I tried to make a some-dir/etc/trusted.gpg.d and copied the gpg
files to that folder. But I do not know how to write the apt.conf even after reading the doc.
I tried to add the repo manually to my temporal sources.list.d as this tutorial said. But I failed because I do not know the repo's URL. I tried to get the url from the gpg file, but it is difficult without root privilege.


Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

@user68186 I am using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Please add this information in your question.  There is no easy way to install an app in Ubuntu without root. Unless there is an appimage.

if you do not own the system you should not be doing this; if you could I'd say it is a big security holw; w/o sudo all you have is your /home and what the admin allowed you to use. if you do have sudo.... use it. It exists for a reason.

The relevant apt.conf key would be Dir::Etc::trustedparts I think (take a look at the output of apt-config dump, for example apt-config dump | grep -i gpg). However since you must have administrator privileges to edit the apt.conf I too am puzzled why you want to do this.

@Rinzwind @steeldriver I want to do so because I want to make a custom apt.conf, and then use apt-get source -c some-dir/apt.conf to install package in custom location witout root, as suggested by this link
